# JavaScript - I get an error in Firebug

Tags: javascript

I am searching through a string trying to count the number of occurrences of @@ (two @ signs in a row).  My code works well when the count is greater than 0, but I get an error in Firebug when the occurrence is zero.

This throws an error:

```
var str = "This string has no at signs!";
var pcount = str.match(/@@/g).length;
alert(pcount);

var str = "This string has @@ one pair of signs!";
var pcount = str.match(/@@/g).length;
alert(pcount);

var str = "This @@ string has @@ two pairs of signs!";
var pcount = str.match(/@@/g).length;
alert(pcount);
```

The error I get in Firebug is:

```
str.match(/@@/g) is null
[Break On This Error] var pcount = str.match(/@@/g).length;
```

What I want is for pcount to be zero if no @@ is found.

Can you help?

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
ANSWER

I ended up using a combination of your answers.  Thanks so much for your help!!!

```
var NewRows = getRowCount(ThisTextLen);
var Match = ThisText.match(/@@/g);
var ParagraphCount = 0;
if (Match != null) {
    ParagraphCount = ThisText.match(/@@/g).length;
    NewRows = NewRows + ParagraphCount;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
var match = str.match(/@@/g); 
var pcount = 0;

if (match != null) { 
     pcount = str.match(/@@/g).length; 
}

alert(pcount);
```

Comment: Mike, thanks for your answer. It seemed to be the clearest, most easily readable answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can write:

```
var pcount = (str.match(/@@/g) || []).length;
```

In case there is no match (the return value of `str.match(/@@/g)` will be `null`, which evaluates to `false`), the `length` property of the empty array will be accessed.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
var matched = str.match(/@@/g);

if(matched == null)
    pcount = 0;
else
    pcount = matched.length;
```

(or something more idiomatic like what Felix suggested, but this is the same idea)

Answer (score 0):

Because no matches for /@@/, that is reason to return null object, so what you can do is

```
var str = "This  string has  two pairs of signs!";
var matches = str.match(/@@/gi);
var pcount = matches != null ? matches.length : 0;
alert(pcount);
```

this will work fine

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = "This @@ string has @@ two pairs of signs!";
var pcount = 0;
if(str.match(/@@/g)!=null)
    pcount =str.match(/@@/g).length;
alert(pcount);
```

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/markdown to learn how to format the text and code properly.